# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" in VueJS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a table with the ability to add new items and edit existing ones (with the edit button being next to each entry). I have an issue with it whereby if you were to add a new item, NOT refresh the page, but then go to edit the item, it will edit it on Vue but not pass the edit back to the database. When you go to edit an item, the PUT URL returns a 404 error. If however, you refresh the page after adding an item, you can edit it perfectly fine. Any ideas what I've done wrong, or maybe forgotten to add? Same for the delete method too.

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            dialog: false,
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Question',
                    align: 'left',
                    sortable: true,
                    value: 'question',
                    width: '25%'
                },
                { text: 'Answer', value: 'answer', width: '55%' },
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false, width: '20%' },
            ],
            questions: [],
            editedIndex: -1,
            editedItem: {
                question: '',
                answer: ''
            },
            defaultItem: {
                question: '',
                answer: ''
            },
        }),

        computed: {
            formTitle () {
                return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
            },
        },

        watch: {
            dialog (val) {
                val || this.close()
            },
        },

        created () {
            this.initialize();
            this.loadUsers();
        },

        methods: {
            initialize () {
                this.questions = []
            },
            loadUsers(){
                if (axios == null) {
                    return;
                }
                axios.get('/api/faq').then(res=>{
                    if(res.status === 200){
                        this.questions=res.data;
                    }
                }).catch(err=>{
                    console.log(err);
                });
            },

            editItem (item) {
                this.editedIndex = this.questions.indexOf(item);
                this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
                this.dialog = true
            },

            deleteItem (item) {
                const index = this.questions.indexOf(item);
                confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') &&
                axios.destroy('/api/faq/' + this.questions[this.editedIndex].id).then(response =>{
                    this.questions.splice(index, 1);
                    }).catch(error=>{
                        console.log('Deleting error')
                    })
            },

            close () {
                this.dialog = false;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
                    this.editedIndex = -1
                }, 300)
            },

            saveToServer () {
                if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
                    // Edit item
                    Object.assign(this.questions[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem);
                    axios.put('/api/faq/' + this.questions[this.editedIndex].id, this.editedItem).then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                } else {
                    //New item
                    this.questions.push(this.editedItem);
                    axios.post('/api/faq', this.editedItem).then(function (response) {
                        console.log('Before');
                        this.id = response.id;
                        console.log('After');
                        Object.assign(this.questions[this.editedIndex], this);
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }

                this.close()
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Store Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {       
        $id = faq::insertGetId($request->all());
        return Response:: json([
            'status' => 'ok',
            'id' => $id,
        ], 200);
    }
```

Update Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        faq::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
        return response(['message' => 'Success']);

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.questions[this.editedIndex]` returns a question?

Comment: How can I check at that stage?

Comment: you might want to save this in a variable first, then check if the value in that variable is not null or undefined. Its possible that there's nothing in that index.

Comment: yeah pretty sure there's not. What might be  causing it to be null?